# How to update a SPListitem whithout change its "modified" and "modified By" column value?

Tags: 2007

I have to update only one column of Sharepoint list in server side console application.

However, if i try to update the SPListitem , the "modified" and "modified by" column will be auto update..
So how to update the list item without change the "modified"  and "modified By" column value?

some code:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    //get itemsite, itemsubsite, fileURL andimageData by item;
    web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(itemsite, itemSubsite, fileURL), nImageData, true);//to replace the same file..
}
```

trying:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
     //get itemsite, itemsubsite, fileURL andimageData by item;
    DateTime modified = (DateTime)doc["Modified"];
    string modifiedBy = (string)doc["Modified By"];
    web.Files.Add(Path.Combine(itemsite, itemSubsite, fileURL), nImageData, true);
    doc["Modified"] = modified;
    doc["Modified By"] = modifiedBy;
    item.Update();//error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach (var item in items)
{
    item["columnOne"] = "SharePoint";
    item.SystemUpdate();
}
```

use it it like this. Instead of update, use systemupdate

Comment: sorry gautam. i modified my code..